# $scope.apply() in code causing error for a unit test having scope.apply()

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have a function in controller file say

```
function getMeData(){
 service().then(function(response){
   vm.arrayOfObj = response;
  getMeValueUpdated(someresponse);
})
}


function getMeValueUpdated(someresponse){
  for(i=0;i<=vm.arrayOfObj.length;i++){
    if(condition){
       vm.arrayOfObj[i] = someresponse
  }
 }
$scope.apply(); // to update data on view
}
```

In unit tests

I am resolving the promise

```
it('title', function(){
  ...
  defer.resolve(fakeresponse);
  $scope.apply();
  ...
})
```

the tests when reach to scope.apply in code throws error- digest cycle already in progress.

I know it would be too hard to predict solution without plunk. But some hint would be helpful.

Comment: are you *sure* that `$scope.$apply()` is even necessary in this instance?  this code all appears to be code angular could detect changes in already;  granted this is pseudocode, but incorrectly adding `$scope.$apply()` when it's not really needed is a pretty common issue in angular.

Comment: you're already updating `vm.arrayOfObj` which will cause a digest cycle. You should not need to call `$scope.apply()`

Comment: Thanks for your replies. scope.apply is required as the UI will not update with the new values without it.